# Facebook, PHP button to post to my wall?

Tags: php, facebook, button

For my Facebook application, I am trying to add a submit button to post something to my wall.
I try to call the function with $_POST['submit'], but it doesn't work. I have also tried to call the php code as function.

Submit:

```
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Post to my wall" />

<?php
if(isset($_POST['submit'])) {
$result = $facebook->api('/me/feed/', 'post', $attachment);
}
?>
```

Function:

```
<form name ="form" method ="post" action = postfunction()> 
<input type="button" value="Post to my wall" />
</form>

<?php
postfunction() {
$result = $facebook->api('/me/feed/', 'post', $attachment);
}
?>
```

Do you have any idea?

Thank you.

Comment: You opening <?php tag is wrong..... Is this deliberate in your question? Do a var_dump of $result to see what your getting back.

Comment: my mistake, it is not the problem

Comment: The second code sample will definitely not work as you can't call PHP functions from HTML/Javascript.  Are you getting any errors when you run the first code sample?

Answer (score 0):

You can't post anything to your facebook wall untill your facebook application has the **publish_stream** token. if you are having it than your code for post: $facebook->api('/me/feed/', 'post', $attachment) shall work.